# How to prove the two dimensional distribution is Delta function?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Let $f(t,x)=\frac{Y(t)}{a(\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}},$ $Y(t)$ is Heaviside function. Prove that $$\partial_tf(t,x)-\partial^2_xf(t,x)=\delta_{(0,0)}$$ in distribution $\mathcal{D}'(R^2).$ I am familar with one dimensional,but I have some problem to compute the two dimensional distribution. It would be nice if you can give me some trick. Do I need use tensor product?

Comment: The trick is still the same: apply the distribution to some test function and have the derivatives start on that test function, then use integration by parts and take limits until you have $\phi(0,0)$

Comment: But I can not get the final results. It would be nice if you give a detail calculatiuon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $f(t, x)\in L^1_{\text{loc}}({\mathbb R}^2)\subset {\cal D}'({\mathbb R}^2)$ because $f\in L^1(I_t\times {\mathbb R_x})$ for every bounded interval $I$. Let $\phi\in {\cal D}({\mathbb R}^2)$, one has
\begin{equation}
\langle\partial_t f - \partial^2_x f, \phi\rangle = \int_{\mathbb R^2}f(t, x)(-\partial_t\phi(t, x) - \partial^2_x\phi(t, x)) d t d x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\int_{[\epsilon,+\infty)\times {\mathbb R_x}}f(t, x)(-\partial_t\phi(t, x) - \partial^2_x\phi(t, x)) d t d x
\end{equation}
Cut the integral in two integrals, integrate by parts in order to remove the derivatives on $\phi$.

Use the derivatives
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}{\partial }_{t} \left({t}^{{-1}/2} {e}^{{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{4 t}}}\right)&=&\left(\frac{{x}^{2}}{4} {t}^{{-5}/2}-\frac{1}{2} {t}^{{-3}/2}\right) {e}^{{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{4 t}}}\\
{\partial }_{x} \left({t}^{{-1}/2} {e}^{{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{4 t}}}\right)&=&-\frac{x}{2} {t}^{{-3}/2} {e}^{{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{4 t}}}\\
{\partial }_{x}^{2} \left({t}^{{-1}/2} {e}^{{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{4 t}}}\right)&=&\left(\frac{{x}^{2}}{4} {t}^{{-5}/2}-\frac{1}{2} {t}^{{-3}/2}\right) {e}^{{-\frac{{x}^{2}}{4 t}}}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

Comment: I also use this method, but I can not get the results. because $\partial_t f(t,x)-\partial^2_x f(t,x)=\frac{Y'(t)}{a(\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}$

Comment: $\partial_t f(t,x)=\frac{Y'(t)}{a(\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}-\frac{Y(t) t^{-1}}{a(\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}+\frac{Y(t)x^2 t^{-2}}{8a(\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}.$ $\partial_x^2 f(t,x)-\frac{Y(t) t^{-1}}{a(\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}+\frac{Y(t)x^2 t^{-2}}{8a(\pi t)^{\frac{1}{2}}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4t}}.$

Comment: I can not get $\phi(0,0)$

Comment: See my edit with the derivatives. Don't use $Y'(t)$, use the integral over $[\epsilon, +\infty)$ instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.